# CALLING A WEB SERVICE FROM THE CODE (NODE.jS) I GET ECONNRESET

Tags: soap, soapui, econnreset

Unfortunately I cannot overcome a problem by making a SAOP request. The problem is that I always get ECONNRESET from node.js.
Strangely, with SOAPUI everything works without problems. For the moment I have tried to do the following tests without getting results:

1. Turn off all antivirus
2. Try to call the service from postman
   Now I wanted to try to write the code in Java but I'm not sure if it makes sense and while I think of a solution I write here hoping that someone can help me. I provide some information:
   Thanks in advance for any suggestions

From Node.js I raised the debug level the error I get is the following:

Error: **ECONNRESET read**

```
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal / stream_base_commons.js: 201: 27)
at Socket.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js: 867: 35)
at tickOnSocket (_http_client.js: 672: 10)
at onSocketNT (_http_client.js: 723: 5)
at processTicksAndRejections 
(internal / process / task_queues.js: 80: 21)
at ClientRequest.onSocket (_http_client.js: 711: 11)
at setRequestSocket (_http_agent.js: 366: 7)
at handleSocketCreation_Inner (_http_agent.js: 359: 7)
at oncreate (_http_agent.js: 231: 5)
at Agent.createSocket (_http_agent.js: 236: 5)
at Agent.addRequest (_http_agent.js: 193: 10)
at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js: 276: 16)
at Object.request (http.js: 44: 10)
at Request.start
```

**With SOAPUI everything works without problems:**

Some information about the service runned correctly from soapUI:

**---------------------------SOAPUI REQUEST-----------------------------------**

**POST** http: // MY-IP: 7563 / recorderstatusservice / recorderstatusservice2.asmx HTTP / 1.1

**Accept-Encoding**: gzip, deflate

**Content-Type**: text / xml; charset = UTF-8

**SOAPAction**: "http://videoos.net/2/XProtectCSRecorderStatus2/GetRecorderStatus"

**Content-Length**: 375

**Host**: MY-IP : 7563

**Connection**: Keep-Alive

**User-Agent**: Apache-HttpClient / 4.1.1 (java 1.5)

**------------------------------SOAPUI RESPONSE------------------------------**

**HTTP / 1.1 200 OK**

**Server**: XProtect Recording Server 12.2a

**Dates**: Fri, Mar 19 2021 21:45:37 GMT

**Cache-Control**: private, max-age = 0

**Content-Type**: text / xml; charset = utf-8

**Content-Length**: 488

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests to understand I tried to use another nodes module called SOAP and I got over the problem.